# python modify string insert into dict

Tags: python, performance, list, dictionary

I open a .txt file and readlines

```
.txt contents = html_log:Bob -1.2 -0.25 4:53 1 0:02 2 1 3 html_log:John 26.6 0.74 36:00 -4 3 25 26 1:57 74 12 16 -1.11 html_log:Bob -1.2 -0.25 4:53 1 0:04 2 1 3 

change = str(textfile)

pattern2 = re.compile("html_log:(?P<name>[^ ]*)(?: [^\s]+){4} (?P<score>[^ ]*)")

try:
    mylist2=sorted(pattern2.findall(change), key=lambda x: float(x[1]), reverse=True)
except ValueError:
    mylist2=sorted(pattern2.findall(change), key=lambda x: float('0'), reverse=True)
```

produces

```
mystr = ('Bob', '0:02'), ('John', '3'),('Bob', '0:02')
```

What i'm trying to do is find out if the  value is not a valid int ie. 0:02, and if it isn't replace it with 0.

i'm trying to have a result of :

```
('Bob', '0'), ('John', '3')
```

I have tried to put the [k] and [v] into my dict and add the values of [v] but it isn't working because of the invaild numbers.

```
mic = defaultdict(int)

for k,v in mylist2:
    mic[k] += re.sub(' ^\d*:\d*','0',v)
```

did not work. And produces typeerror

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python26/myfile.py", line 44, in <module>
    mic[k] += re.sub(' ^\d*:\d*','0',v)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "did not work".  Did it raise an error or just not give the result you wanted?  If it raised an error, please edit your post to include the complete traceback.

Comment: Also, please clarify what you want a bit more.  For example, where does `mystr` come from?  I don't see it in your code.

Comment: Sorry I hope I clarified that @SethMMorton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `try...except` clause to weed out the non-integers:

```
def makeInt(val, default=0):
    try: 
        return int(val)
    except ValueError:
        return default
```

Then you can replace this line `mic[k] += re.sub(' ^\d*:\d*','0',v)` with the following:

```
mic[k] += makeInt(v)
```

**Edit:** If you want to use a value other than `0` to replace non-integers, just add it as another argument:

```
mic[k] += makeInt(v, 1)
```

Comment: could i make the except change the non-integer into one @ASGM

Comment: @user2371027 you sure could!  You can make it return whatever value you want, just by changing `return 0` to `return 1`.

Comment: @user2371027 I've adjusted the function so that the default non-integer value is 0, but you can pass a different default value as an argument.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help ASGM, I should have asked the question better.

Comment: mic[k] += makeInt[v]
TypeError: 'function' object is unsubscriptable

Comment: why isn't it letting me use the function

Comment: `makeInt[v]` should be `makeInt(v)` - the difference is the parentheses rather than square brackets.  With `()` it's a function, but with `[]` it thinks you're to access an element with an index inside `makeInt`, as if it were a list and not a function (that's why you're getting an error).

Comment: I'M About to give up man :( Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python26/myfile.py", line 22, in <module>
    mylist2=sorted(pattern2.findall(change), key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)
  File "C:/Python26/prometheus.py", line 22, in <lambda>
    mylist2=sorted(pattern2.findall(change), key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0:11'

Comment: and my question is just getting voted down :(, might just retire from python lol

Comment: @user2371027, don't give up yet!  Python can be really rewarding.  I think your question is getting voted down because it has a lot of extra complexity that doesn't seem relevant to the question.  In future if you trim down your question to a smaller chunk of code and explain what you've tried so far, you'll be less likely to attract downvotes.